# mysql join excluding from non-index?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to get a list of sales data entries for orders which include a certain product ID but which do not also include a different product ID.  I need customer data from one table and product data (specifically quantity) from another.

'orders' Table with customer data looks something like this:

```
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------+
| OrderID |       CustomerName        | CustomerAddress |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------+
|     123 | Joe Smith                 | 123 wherever st |
|     124 | Jane Doe                  | 555 Fake Rd     |
|     125 | Pete Thompson             | 1600 Main St    |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------+
```

'order_products' Table might look like this:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| OrderID | ProductID | Quantity |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|     123 |       400 |        1 |
|     123 |       401 |        1 |
|     124 |       400 |        2 |
|     125 |       401 |        1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

In this particular example I want to see a result showing just the order that contains ONLY product ID 400 but not 401.  With this fake data it would be a single line result showing this:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+----------+
| OrderID | CustomerName | CustomerAddress | Quantity |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+----------+
|     124 | Jane Doe     | 555 Fake Rd     |        2 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+----------+
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.CustomerName, o.CustomerAddress, op.Quantity
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN order_products op
ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
WHERE op.ProductID = 400
AND op.ProductID != 401
```

But I still get order number 123 returned even though it contains ProductID 401.  I understand why (because order_products contains a line for each product) but I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.CustomerName, o.CustomerAddress, op.Quantity
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN order_products op
ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
WHERE op.ProductID = 400 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM order_products AS op2
                  WHERE op2.orders_id = o.orders_id AND op2.ProductID = 401)
```

This will exclude `orders` records related to  `order_products` records having `ProductID = 401`.

Comment: Why left join instead of inner?

Comment: @Shadow Because it is used in the query of the OP. `INNER JOIN` would be more appropriate here, since `WHERE op.ProductID = 400` makes `LEFT JOIN` equivalent to an `INNER JOIN` anyway.